# Changing the harmony of a motive ''by additions at the end,'' according to Schoenberg

Tags: harmony, composition, motif

Schoenberg says that the harmony of a motive may be changed ''[b]y additions at the end'' (*Fundamentals of musical composition*, page 10). He cites examples 25c-i to illustrate what he means (see picture). Can someone please spell out for me how examples 25c-i illustrate what Schoenberg thinks they illustrate?

[image]

Comment: There are examples of harmonizing of a similar phrase, using a different chord at the end of each time. The chord harmonic function is written under the score. Which part exactly needs clarification?

Comment: Point taken -- the end is being changed. If you're right that that's all that Schoenberg is pointing to, then your comment is a complete answer to my question.

As to why I was confused: I suppose that if the fact that *a different chord is used at the end of each of the examples 25c-i* is all that Schoenberg is pointing to with this example, then I would have expected him to say that the harmony of a motive may be changed "by changing the last harmony" rather than "by additions at the end," since this would then seem to be an example of *replacing material* rather than *adding material*.

Comment: Perhaps that's referring to the fact that in examples a) and b) the harmony is static (only the inversions change), so putting a new chord on beat 4 is considered an addition?

Comment: Wow! I didn't notice that, but that seems right. Thank you. If you post your response as an answer, I will "accept" it.